# How do I create a subfolder in Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless-framework

I'm following this guide

https://sqldusty.com/2017/06/21/how-to-automate-processing-of-azure-analysis-services-models/

In step **4. Configure the Function App**, we need to create a subfolder called bin

> > Select your function, TimerTriggerCSharp1, and expand the View files windows on the far right of your screen.
> >
> > Here you need to add a folder called “bin”. Click Add to do this.

When I click "add", it adds a **file**, not a **folder**. What am I missing>?

[image]

**EDIT:**

In the end I kept getting inconsistent assembly errors, and easily hit the 5 minute timeout limitation. So I looked into Azure Automation instead. This appears to be a much simpler way to achieve what I need. I'm just having difficulty with the scheduling now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, everyone forgets to mention that the thing you add should be named

```
bin\
```

not

```
bin
```

Comment: awesome.. thanks! (also works with other folder names)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using precompiled Functions with new VS2017 15.3 tooling. Then you won't have to create any folders manually, just reference the NuGet packages that you need.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a lot more usable. If only old documentation had references to new documentation !